# How to get PAGE_NAME value in FitNesse test?

Tags: fitnesse, fit-framework

I see that there are *PAGE_NAME* and *PAGE_PATH* global variables but I can't find a way to get their value in neither Fit pages nor Fit SetUp / SuiteSetUp pages - I tried obvious ways, all came back as "undefined variable".

Is there any other way to get a current page's/test's name?

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks!
Oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear from your question what you've tried, but based on the [FitNesse user guide](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide#VARIABLES), variable names need to be escaped like so: `${name}`.

Including `${PAGE_NAME}` or `${PAGE_PATH}` in a test or suite works OK in my local FitNesse.

Comment: It appears I was playing with the older version on FitNesse, the one I have installed on our CI server - and that version did't have those variables. I just tried with more recent FitLibrary/FitNesse, and I was able to get the Page_Name variable working. Thanks!